# C++. How to speed up the execution of a method or cycle?

Tags: c++, time, cycle, const-iterator

I had one problem. It is necessary to speed up the operation of one method. In this method there are three or four cycles of this type:

```
for (vector<(ANY_TYPE) *>::const_iterator iter = VECTOR_NAME.begin(); iter != VECTOR_NAME.end(); ++iter)
```

The duration of one such cycle can vary from 0 to 1 second. But in this method, I have such cycles called several thousand times, of which there are more than a hundred cases when such a cycle lasts one second. In total, due to this, the execution of my main method takes between 155 and 190 seconds.

I would like to speed up the execution of this method. Is there an identical cycle in C++ that would almost always take zero seconds or ? Is there another way for me to speed up the execution of the method? I am using C++ standard 11.

Can anyone recommend anything? Thanks in advance.

I've tried replacing similar cycles with cycles like:

```
for (ANY_TYPE * &iter: VECTOR_NAME)
```

But nothing helps. And I think the use of such a cycle is illogical.

Comment: Are you doing something in this for loops?

Comment: Please show a [mre], it's unlikely that the for loops themselves are the source of your performance issues, the body of the loops of the likely culprit. Are you using compiler optimisations?

Comment: Depending on problem there are different ways (named "algorithms") how to get lower time complexity than naive brute force stack of loops or deep recursions. Unfortunately we have no idea about problem, so can suggest nothing.

Comment: The structure of your for loop looks fine, the performance issue must be from what's in your loop body. Many nested loops possible?